# Extracting the most common words and then append to a csv file with python

Tags: python

So i'm trying to extract the most used words from a .txt file, and then put the 4 most common words into a csv file. (and then append if need be), At the moment it's extracting the most common words, and appending to a csv file. But it's appending each letter to a cell.

python

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv   
fields=['first','second','third']


# Read input file, note the encoding is specified here 
# It may be different in your text file
file = open('pyTest.txt', encoding="utf8")
a= file.read()
# Stopwords
stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords.txt'))
stopwords = stopwords.union(set(['mr','mrs','one','two','said']))
# Instantiate a dictionary, and for every word in the file, 
# Add to the dictionary if it doesn't exist. If it does, increase the count.
wordcount = {}
# To eliminate duplicates, remember to split by punctuation, and use case demiliters.
for word in a.lower().split():
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace(":","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("!","")
    word = word.replace("â€œ","")
    word = word.replace("â€˜","")
    word = word.replace("*","")
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
# Print most common word
n_print = int(input("How many most common words to print: "))
print("\nOK. The {} most common words are as follows\n".format(n_print))
word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word in word_counter.most_common(n_print):

    print(word[0])

# Close the file

file.close()

with open('old.csv', 'a') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        for word in word_counter.most_common(4):
            print(word)
            writer.writerow(word[0])
```

Output csv file

```
p,i,p,e

d,i,a,m,e,t,e,r

f,i,t,t,i,n,g,s

o,u,t,s,i,d,e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to extract the first item of each sub-list in the list returned by the `most_common` method as a row instead:

```
with open('old.csv', 'a') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(word for word, _ in word_counter.most_common(4))
```

Comment: Thankyou that is adding for example this ('pipe', 27). I need to extract just the word part.